# After using the command-line option --old-file, Make still rebuilds the target. Why?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary):***

> `-o FILE`
>   
>   `--old-file=FILE`
>   
>   `--assume-old=FILE`
>   
>   
>        Do not remake the file FILE even if it is older than its
>        prerequisites, and do not remake anything on account of changes in
>        FILE.  Essentially the file is treated as very old and its rules
>        are ignored.

***And there, [elsewhere](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Avoiding-Compilation.html#Avoiding-Compilation):***

> If you have already changed the header file at a time when some files
>   do need recompilation, it is too late to do this.  Instead, you can use
>   the `-o FILE` flag, which marks a specified file as "old" (*note Summary
>   of Options: Options Summary.).  This means that the file itself will not
>   be remade, and nothing else will be remade on its account.  Follow this
>   procedure:

***Now, the following - rather simple - makefile:***

```make
# Create an out-of-date target, where 'new' is "newer" than "all".
$(shell touch all)
$(shell sleep 0.1)
$(shell touch new)

all:: new
    echo '$@'
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
$ make -oall
echo 'all'
all
```

What a disaster!

Didn't the quote above just read:

> ***Do not remake the file*** FILE ***even if it is older*** than its
>    prerequisites, and do not remake anything on account of changes in

But, doing exactly like that, and telling Make, that `all` is an `old-file`, did NOT "deter" it from re-building it. What?!

Answer (score 2):

`make` rebuilds the target `all` because you have specified it as a [double-colon](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html) rule. If we were to alter the `makefile` to be

```
# Create an out-of-date target, where 'new' is "newer" than "all".
$(shell touch all)
$(shell sleep 1)
$(shell touch new)

all: new
    echo '$@'
```

running `make -oall` would produce `make: 'all' is up to date.`, the expected output.

**[Note]** On my system I had to increase the sleep timeout to 1, to reproduce the error in the question. *GNU Make 4.1* on *OS X 10.10.4*.

---

**[Disclaimer]** I am not 100% sure why the `-o` option is handled differently with double-colon rules and I can't find anything to suggest why. I will give my interpretation of it in the hope that it will help.

---

The [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html) states

> Double-colon rules are somewhat obscure and not often very useful; they provide a mechanism for cases in which the method used to update a target differs depending on which prerequisite files caused the update, and such cases are rare.

Based on this I would suggest part of the *obscurity* of double-colon rules is that they do not adhere to the `-o` option specification because of the use cases they are meant for, i.e.

> to update a target ... depending on which prerequisite files caused the update

With this in mind double-colon rules should execute if **any** of their **prerequisites** are **newer** than the target **regardless** of any **other options** specified in the `makefile` or on the command line.